# Difference in difference with binary outcome -- test parallel trend assumption

Tags: regression, econometrics, difference-in-difference

I am performing this two-period difference-in-difference model,

$y_{i,t} = \beta_1 T_{i} + \beta_2 \text{ after}_{i, t} + \gamma T_{i} \text{ after}_{i, t} + \mathbf{x}_{i}^T \boldsymbol{\alpha}  + \epsilon_{i, t}$

where $y_{it}$ is an outcome variable that equals 1 if individual $i$ adopts a behavior at time period $t$. Individuals can only adopt once ($\sum_{t} y_{it} = 1$). In addition, individuals cannot adopt before the treatment period.

**My question is how to examine parallel trend assumption when outcomes can only be 0 pre-treatment.**

The following two options do not work in our setting:

(1) We cannot directly compare the pre-treatment trend between the treatment and outcome groups, because pre-treatment outcomes are all 0.

(2) Section 6 (pp 333) of Finkelstein (2002) describes a parallel trend assumption test: “The effect of tax subsidies to employer-provided supplementary health insurance: evidence from Canada” mentioned one falsification test, but it seems that it can only be applied to scenarios where outcome variable (adoption) can be 1 before treatment (which is why Eq.3 can be used together with data in 1989 and 1991).

Much appreciate your help. Thank you!

*Finkelstein, Amy. "The effect of tax subsidies to employer-provided supplementary health insurance: evidence from Canada." Journal of Public Economics 84, no. 3 (2002): 305-339.*

Comment: Welcome. So the outcome for both groups is exactly 0 pre-period?

Comment: Exactly. The outcomes for both groups are 0 pre- the analysis period. In the meantime, for the treatment group, the outcome cannot be 1 before they are treated.